# Query to find table use in files not working after computer restart

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I was working on a SQL query that allowed me to look for the use of certain keywords in files like functions, stored procedures, triggers, etc. The query was returning 54 rows like I expected. But after shutting down my PC last night and booting it up today the query returned 0 rows instead of the 54 that I saw yesterday. How does the result of this query change after restarting my PC? Here is the query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT so.name, so.xtype
FROM syscomments sc
INNER JOIN sysobjects so ON sc.id = so.id
WHERE sc.TEXT LIKE '%TestDatabase%'
ORDER BY so.xtype
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Use [YOUR DATABASE NAME]
```

The run the query it should work.  Best guess is that you are on the master dbf and thus finding no results.

```
SELECT DISTINCT so.name, so.xtype
FROM [your dbf].dbo.syscomments sc
INNER JOIN [your dbf].dbo.sysobjects so ON sc.id = so.id
WHERE sc.TEXT LIKE '%QAD_DATA%'
ORDER BY so.xtype
```

This would also do it.  It is because syscomments and sysbojects are liked to each dbf

Comment: Wow, that worked! But I don't get how it would of worked yesterday without the `USE` clause. I will upvote this tomorrow, I used up all of my upvotes lol.

Comment: Sounds like you just weren't in the right database. Your default one is probably different from the one you were wanting to read from. The sysobjects table is different on each database. If Stephen answered your question, please consider marking it as the answer (much better than upvoting). :)

Comment: @april4181 I was going to upvote it after my comment was answered (which you did). Thanks for clearing that up for me :).